# Python Json to csv， Extract the specified keys，KeyError:

Tags: python, json, csv

I need to convert json to csv, I just want to extract some keys in the file, but some keys do not exist in the json file, I hope it can automatically fill in these non-existent keys

```py
import csv
import json
import sys
import codecs

def trans(path):
    jsonData = codecs.open('C:/Users/jeri/Desktop/1.json', 'r', 'utf-8')
    # csvfile = open(path + '.csv', 'w') 
    # csvfile = open(path + '.csv', 'wb') 
    csvfile = open('C:/Users/jeri/Desktop/1.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')  
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    keys = ['dob','firstname','lastname']
    writer.writerow(keys)

    for line in jsonData:
        dic = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow([dic['dob'],dic['firstname'],dic['lastname'],])

    jsonData.close()
    csvfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = str(sys.argv[0])
    print(path)
    trans(path)
```

Console prompt：：

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeri\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    trans(path)
  File "C:\Users\jeri\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\main.py", line 17, in trans
    writer.writerow([dic['dob'],dic['firstname'],dic['lastname'],])
KeyError: 'dob'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key `'dob'` might be missing, instead of `dic['dob']`, do `dic.get('dob', None)`. That provides the default you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would solve your problem.
(I defined a function to test the existence of each item in json, if exists it return the value and if it doesn't exists it returns 'N/A')

```
def getValue(dic, item):
    try:
        return dic[item]
    except:
        return 'N/A'

for line in jsonData:
    dic = json.loads(line)
    writer.writerow([getValue(dic, 'dob'), getValue(dic, 'firstname'), getValue(dic, 'lastname'),])
```

Comment: Inliners are always beautiful.

Comment: I'm  not sure that this is an improvement on the method `dict.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can transform your for loop into something like this.

```
for line in jsonData:
    dic = json.loads(line)
    dob = dic['dob'] if "dob" in dic else None
    firstname = dic['firstname'] if "firstname" in dic else None
    lastname = dic['lastname'] if "lastname" in dic else None
    writer.writerow([dob,firstname,lastname])
```